# In extjs4 how to get edited values of combobox

Tags: combobox, extjs4

i am working in extjs4. I have view with component as=

```
xtype : 'comboboxselect',
id : 'Id1',
displayField: 'emailAddress',
typeAhead: true,
editable : true,
hideTrigger:true,
forceSelection: false,
```

i want to allow users to enter new emailIds also. So i kept editable as true. But when i am trying to get combobox's selected value on sumbit button click, its not giving me newly inserted emailsId's in combobox.I tries it as =

```
Ext.getCmp('Id1').getSubmitData()   or   Ext.getCmp('Id1').getRawValue()
```

But its not giving me newly inserted emailId's. So how to perform this in extjs4

Answer (score 1):

If this is `Ext.form.field.ComboBox` (`xtype:'combobox'`) then `getValue()` returns the current value of the combobox. More info available on [sencha docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-method-getValue)